# OnItemSelectedListener, ListView and item recycling

Tags: android, listview

I have a bunch of items in a ListView. Each item contains several editable views. I want to save the changes the user makes to these. The event for the save to occur is when an the item loses focus.

I currently see 2 ways:

```
    View.OnFocusChangeListener() with  onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus)
```

This works but is messy since each item contains several editable Views. I would much rather save when the whole item is defocused.  My attempts to simplify so far have only complicated things.

If there was a OnItemDeSelectedListener it would be perfect, but there is only the opposite:

```
    AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() with onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l)
```

On the surface this looks good. I just create the variable lastSelectedView so I know what the last selected (deselected) item was.
The problem is how ListView recycles views. I believe there is no guarantee that the adapter has not recycled lastSelectedView and thus changed the data it contains. Is this a reasonable assumption?

**Is there a reasonable way to get around the recycling view problem with OnItemSelectedListener?**

Comment: Why are you storing the view that was last modified instead of the underlying model? You should probably be updating the data in your list view's adapter after each modification instead. Or since you want to do this on focus change of the item, create a local copy of the data type the adapter is holding, but not the view.

Comment: Hmm... Thanks for this. You helped me realize my error. The reason there is no OnItemDeSelectedListener is because the list item (using the recommended Adapter implementation) gets recycled as soon as it goes off screen regardless if the item is still selected or not.

I'll post my solution once I am able to meet my requirements

Comment: I think the reason there isn't a deselected listener is because there isn't really a general way to handle deslection for multi and single selection modes.

Comment: Just as a follow up I gave up on this. It seems too much of an abuse of the expected use of ListView. I've learned that trying to go against android design patterns is futile and just leads to headaches and buggy code! I ended up just editing the items in a separate activity

Answer (score 0):

If you're using single selection, then selecting another item will "deselect" the current item. At the time, you could apply your changes to the locally stored copy of the item that was in the adapter. I don't believe you should use the view being passed in onItemSelected() or onItemDeselected() as a model for your edited data. Like I said, it's best to create an item of the adapter data type that is currently being edited, and in the onSelectedListener(), you would apply the changes from the edited item to the corresponding item in the adapter. Something like this:

```
    ListView myListView;
    Object objectCurrentlyEditing;
    int positionCurrentlyEditing;
    myListView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int position, long arg3) 
        {
            myListView.getAdapter().getItem(positionCurrentlyEditing).update(objectCurrentlyEditing);

            positionCurrentlyEditing = position;
            objectCurrentlyEditing = myListView.getAdapter().getItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

The update function would be how list item are saved after they are no longer selected. This method assumes you're using single choice mode though.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is similar to other answers here, with an attempt to address the recycling problem a bit differently - this is going to be a bit circular so read twice:
In onItemSelected, first use the data you've saves on the previous call to onItemSelected.
Than save the data from the current view (sent to onItemSelected as parameter) to final variable or field to be used on the next call to onItemSelected.

for example, here's a model object:
    public class YourModelObject{
        public YourModelObject(String dataString, int dataInt){
            this.dataString = dataString;
            this.dataInt = dataInt;
        }
        private String dataString;
        private int dataInt;
        //here are some getters, setters and methods...
    }

and here's the listview displaying it:

```
ListView myListView;

ArrayList<YourModelObject> listOfModelObjects;
//somewhere before onItemSelected listOfModelObjects is initialized with data

final YourModelObject lastItemData; //this can either be final, or an instance variable.

myListView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int i, long l)
    {
        //use last saved data:
        if (lastItemData != null){
            //do some stuff with lastItemData
        }
        //save current data for next call:
        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(someId);
        NumberPicker np = (NumberPicker) view.findViewById(anotherId);
        String dataString = tv.getText().toString();
        int dataInt = np.getValue();
        lastItemData = new YourModelObject(dataString , dataInt);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    }
});
```

this way you only manipulate your data after item lost focus (and new one selected) and you are positive about the consistency of your data, as you don't really hold the view that is being recycled but only the data it used to contain. Hope you find it usefull :)